# Laplace transform - frequency differentiation property (generalization)

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, laplace-transform

Let $\mathcal{L(f(t);s)}$ be the Laplace transform of a function $f$. It is known that the Laplace transform of $\mathcal{L}{(t^nf(t);s)}$ is given as (frequency differentiation property)
\begin{equation}
\mathcal{L}{(t^nf(t);s)} = (-1)^n \frac{d^n}{ds^n}\mathcal{L}(f(t);s),
\end{equation}
that is, in terms of the $n$-th derivative of $\mathcal{L(f(t);s)}$. Is there a closed-form for the folowing Laplace transform
\begin{equation} 
\mathcal{L}{(t^pf(t);s)},
\end{equation}
where $p \in \mathbb{R}$ with $p \geq 1$?